# Fedora: How do I boot into the LiveOS from the .iso?

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a custom USB stick with maybe around ~10 Linux Distros, and 3 versions of Windows for some reason. I just drop the .iso files into /Linux, and then use GRUB to boot into those .isos. Some example entries:

```
menuentry "ubuntu 20.04" --class ubuntu {
    set isofile="/Linux/ubuntu.iso"
    loopback loop ($BOOT)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=$isofile boot=casper ro quiet splash
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Manjaro 18.0.4" --class manjaro {
    set isofile="/Linux/manjaro.iso"
    set imgdevpath="/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID"    
    loopback loop ($BOOT)$isofile
    linux (loop)/boot/vmlinuz-x86_64 img_dev=$imgdevpath img_loop=$isofile ro quiet splash
    initrd (loop)/boot/initramfs-x86_64.img
}
menuentry "Silverblue 34 (Install only)" --class silverblue {
    set isofile="/Linux/silverblue.iso"
    loopback loop ($BOOT)$isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:UUID=$UUID:$isofile ro quiet splash
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

Now, I can take that Silverblue entry, and point it to the Fedora.iso file. It'll boot just fine, but it only goes straight to the installer. While Silverblue doesn't have the LiveOS folder in it's .iso, Fedora does.

How would I adjust the boot entry to get it into boot into the Live environment?

Comment: You can find several links that look promising (to help you solve the problem), when you search the internet with the following search string: **grub menuentry fedora live**

Comment: I was halfway there, but this helped a great deal. One of the search results showed I needed to add `iso-scan/filename=$isofile`. Thank you for embarrassingly helping me to learn how to search. XD

Comment: Congratulations @gdi and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the correct menuentry for me.

```
menuentry "Fedora 34" --class fedora {
    set isofile="/Linux/fedora.iso"
    loopback loop ($BOOT)$isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=$isofile root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-34-1-2 rd.live.image ro
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

Apparently, `inst.stage2` is used to point to an install source. ([Source](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f34/install-guide/advanced/Boot_Options/))

So I had to remove that, and add these arguments to get it to boot into the Live environment: `iso-scan/filename=$isofile root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-34-1-2 rd.live.image`.

Without `iso-scan/filename=$isofile`, it couldn't find the .iso file.

`root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-34-1-2` looks like a chroot location. You can find the `CDLABEL` by mounting the .iso file. I imagine using the UUID could work as well but have not tested it.

Not entirely sure what `rd.live.image` does, but it certainly looks relevant, doesn't it? :p It appears to be a dracut option. Probably just letting it know to use a Live environment.